# German spell descriptions for DnD 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, languages

Does anyone have a good site where I can find German translations for all the spells? We are struggling with different translation variants.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests links to infringing content.

Comment: (Anyone wondering about the copyright stuff around translations, these are good lay primers: [Copyright in translations](http://www.translatorsbase.com/articles/42.aspx) [US]; [Translation and Copyright](http://cjam.info/en/legal-informations/copyright/168-translations-and-copyright) [Canada]. It will be similar in other Berne Convention nations.)

Comment: At this time, using a translation of a book that you bought is not an unfair use of the translation... (as long as you do not have to pay the translator for his work, unless said translator pays royalties to the original author.) However, the fact that many companies do no do translation and forbids them is a shame.

Comment: @Alexis Using a translation is not the issue. Sharing the translation is a copyright violation, and we avoid enabling access to pirated material. It sucks, but that's an objection to the law, not evidence that it's legal.

Comment: Sorry did not know that. Can anyone delete this question then?

Comment: Note, that you can hire a translator to take your English D&D 5 ed. book and translate it to German, and then you can use the translation as you would use the book. What would be illegal is either giving away or selling copies of the translation, or - as suggested - if the translator was selling the translations himself (instead of being hired to translate a specific text).

In theory the translator should delete all copies of the source or translated materials after the transaction was finalized, though it would be him whou would break copyright law if he kept it/reselled it.

Answer (score 9):

**No.**

Wizards has not licensed a German translation of D&D 5e. D&D 5e also does not have an open license, so any instance of the text of all the spells appearing on a Web site would be illegal, in any language.

Comment: Sorry did not know that. Can anyone delete this question then?

Comment: I'd actually rather leave it so it doesn't get asked again, it's a common issue.